# pentaho execute multiple sql script in sequence

Tags: pentaho

How can I execute those step in sequence?
each step create a table that the next step will use in a sub-query.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Job you can execute SQL statement in sequence.
You can see my sample from [Here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1y7uP0NGDLJCt-HI8FahQD2iPs59eSyri?usp=sharing)

[image]